# error using write_csv within R Markdown dowcument

Tags: r, r-markdown, tidyverse

When inputting 
`write_csv(MyComplicationData,"Data/MyComplicationData.csv")`
as part of a `.Rmd` file, I get the following error when trying to knit the document:

> Error in open.connection(path, "wb") : cannot open the connection
>   Calls:  ... write_delim -> stream_delim -> open.connection
>   Execution halted

When I input the same command from the console, it works without a problem. 
`MyComplicationData` is a `tibble` with 4812 observations of 7 variables.

Comment: I found the fix.  For some reason, in R markdown, you must use the entire path name and not a relative path name.  When I changed the command to **write_csv(MyComplicationData,"~/Academia/STAT412612/Data/MyComplicationData.csv")** it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the getwd() command that return your working directory if the directory in which you want to save it is inside, otherwise you should give the entire path.
It would give something like this :

```
write_csv(MyComplicationData,paste(getwd(),"/Data/MyComplicationData.csv", sep = "")
```

or

```
paste0(getwd(),"/Data/MyComplicationData.csv")
```